# How do I use an unmanaged dependency in this simple Play example?

Tags: scala, build, playframework-2.0

I am trying to write a Scala Play web service that returns JSON objects and am having trouble calling a function in a dependency. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in this simplified example?

I have a project called SimpleJSONAPI that consists of the following object.

```
package com.github.wpm.SimpleJSONAPI

import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

object SimpleJSONAPI {
  def toJson(s: String): JsValue = Json.toJson(Map("value" -> s))
}
```

Unit tests confirm that given a string it returns a JSON object of the form `{"value":"string"}`.

I have a separate Play 2.2.3 Scala project that I created by typing `play new PlayJSON`. I added the following `json` action to the controller in the generated application.

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

import com.github.wpm.SimpleJSONAPI._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

  def json = {
    val j = SimpleJSONAPI.toJson("The JSON API")
    Action {
      Ok(j)
    }
  }
}
```

I also added this route.

```
GET        /json                controllers.Application.json
```

In the root of the PlayJSON project I have a lib directory that contains the `simplejsonapi_2.11.jar` built by SimpleJSONAPI. This appears to contain the correct code.

```
> jar tf lib/simplejsonapi_2.11.jar 
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/github/
com/github/wpm/
com/github/wpm/SimpleJSONAPI/
com/github/wpm/SimpleJSONAPI/SimpleJSONAPI$.class
com/github/wpm/SimpleJSONAPI/SimpleJSONAPI.class
```

This compiles, but when I try to connect to `localhost:9000/json` I get the following runtime error in the line with the `val j` assignment.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(L/java/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I've also seen the same error in a unit test that exercises the `/json` route with a `FakeRequest`.

If I copy the `toJson` function from the external dependency into the Play application everything works.

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies) I'm doing everything right, and the error message is opaque. Can someone tell me how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with Scala compiler version compatibility. I compiled my `SimpleJSONAPI` dependency with Scala 2.11, while the Play app was being built with Scala 2.10. When I changed the `SimpleJSONAPI` dependency to also build with Scala 2.10, I was able to use it in my Play app.

This was confusing because it's not obvious from the project files which version of Scala a Play app is using, and the error message about `ArrowAssoc` gives no indication that it is a compiler version issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your import is incorrect given how you are using the API.  Either exclude the object name on the import...

```
import com.github.wpm.SimpleJSONAPI._
```

Or change your usage to drop the object name...

```
val j = toJson("The JSON API")
```

Comment: You're right. My `import` line was incorrect. When I fix it I still have a problem. I have updated the text of the question to reflect this.